# Why does Ubuntu 9.04 reset my Windows clock?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ntp, boot, time

I've got a rig with 2 hard drives. I've put Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty) on one of the drives and Windows Vista SP2 runs on the other drive. I went with this approach rather than dual boot since I wanted to be able to swap out the OSes as I please and just keep things clean and separate.

The problem I've been noticing is that when I am in Ubuntu and I reboot into Windows Vista (by selecting the Vista drive at boot time), the Vista clock is always set back by about 5 hours. Also I've noticed that when I try to synchronize the Vista clock, it always errors out on the first attempt, then I have to click "Update now" a second time before the synchronization with the selected NTP server takes effect. Repeated reboots of Vista do not affect the Vista clock so long as I go from Vista back to Vista each time.

Also, the reverse is not true, that is, rebooting Vista and launching Ubuntu does not affect the Ubuntu clock.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Would appreciate any help at all.

**Update**: I should also probably mention that Ubunty is 64-bit and Vista is 32-bit.

Comment: This is an old Linux/BSD and Windows dual boot issue. I would suggest editing the question to reflect the generic nature of the problem.

Comment: Like I mentioned, the 2 OSes are *not* in dual boot, they're on separate SATA hard drives.

Comment: They *are* in dual boot because you boot either one or the other. Dual boot does not mean "in the same hard drive", even if that setup is the most common.

Comment: I always thought multiple drives each with their own OS was called a multi-boot configuration. Anyway I must be mistaken. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it [this problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=382199)?

You need to look at
`/etc/default/rcS` 
and change **UTC=yes** to **UTC=no**.

This makes Ubuntu read and write to the hardware clock in the same way as Windows, using local time instead of UTC.

Comment: Yup sounds like this is it. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Ubuntu, by default will check NTP servers for the correct time, and update the system clock.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to make the change to the windows installation:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
```

Add a new dword named `"RealTimeIsUniversal"` and set it to `1`

Comment: I'd already tried the "accepted" fix which worked for me.

Comment: This would have the added benefit of working if you forgot to change the timezone information after a move.

Comment: I've done this, but every now and then my Windows clock jumps back 6 hours (I'm UDT-6). I then have to go in and have it re-update with the time server.